# sharing files on different subnets on windows

Tags: networking, share, ip-address, static-ip-address

I am getting internet from a WISP close to my house using an out-door wireless network adapter. so first the internet comes to a desktop PC and from there i want to share it using a wireless router between other devices. beside internet sharing, i want devices connected to my wireless router to share files between each other and PC1.
 here is what I've done to get as close as possible to what i need for my network. both devices running windows 8.1.

---

PC1 (deskptop):

```
IP address: 192.168.1.1 
Default gateway: 192.168.1.1
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
```

shared network adapter with Ethernet port on PC1. Ethernet port is connected to WAN port of the router. turned on network discovery.

PC1 Ethernet port :

```
IP address: 192.168.137.1
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
```

Router:

Set to Wireless router Mode.
Static IP address for WAN port in Router:

```
IP address: 192.168.137.42
Default Gateway: 192.168.137.1
Subnet: 255.255.255.0 
DHCP: enabled from 192.168.1.100 to 192.168.1.224
Port forwarding option: (virtual server) :
192.168.1.100 to 192.168.137.1 (forward internal IP to External IP of router)
Forward port: 5900 to 5900
DMZ: enabled for IP address (192.168.1.100)
```

PC2 (Laptop):

```
Static IP address: 192.168.1.100
Subnet: 255.255.255.0 
Default Gateway: 192.168.1.1
```

changed network mode to private. turned on file sharing and network discovery and shared folders.

PC1 can see PC2 using VNC viewer on `192.168.137.42:5900`, Done.
PC1 and PC2 both have internet connection, Done.
PC1 (desktop) can't access files/folders on PC2 (laptop
). that's the problem.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. It may be easier to get a second Ethernet card for PC1 and hook it to one of your routers switch-ports.
   OR
2. If your routers firmware allows it, you could override the default gateway of DHCP clients to use PC1's IP. That wouldn't require a second NIC.